# Fetch two vertices connected multi edges in orientdb

Tags: orientdb, orientjs, nosql

I have this scenario

```
P(V)<--- S(E)----SL(V)
```

Here P and SL are vertices and S is edge.
Now in result I want to fetch all attributes of P , S **also rids** and selected attributes of SL. I was using `fetchplan:in_S:2` but this is not working for me.
I am using orientdb and orientJS(client).

Comment: which query are you running?

Comment: I am using select @this("fetchplan:in_S:2") FROM P

Comment: It should have been something like `P(V)<---S(E)---SL(V) RETURN P.all, S.all, SL.x, SL.y, SL.z` if OrientDb team could have designed not only a very good db capable of conveniently modelling complex interconnected data models of today, but also a declarative querying language that is capable of conveniently modelling that graph modelled data it should resemble, not SQL mess.